# function setQueuePriority has different performance on iOS emulator and on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have two NSIvocationOperations in one NSOperationQueue. And I used setQueuePriority to adjust the execution order of the two operations, 1->2, or 2->1. The code worked well on emulator, however, failed on my iPhone.

My code is like this:

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

NSInvocationOperation *operation1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thread1) object:nil];
[operation1 setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryLow];

NSInvocationOperation *operation2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thread2) object:nil];
[operation2 setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh];

[operationQueue addOperation:operation1];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation2];
```

Operation2 should be executed ahead of operation1 and I saw the same result on emulator. While on iPhone, operation1 was always executed first no matter how I adjusted their QueuePriorities. Why it's like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue priority doesn't guarantee execution order. To quote from Apple's documentation:

> You should use priority values only as needed to classify the relative
>   priority of non-dependent operations. Priority values should not be
>   used to implement dependency management among different operation
>   objects.

If it's important to you that one operation be executed before another you should use operation dependencies instead (via `addDependency:`).

Comment: I make print in each operation, that means they're non-dependent operations, right?

Comment: You say 'Operation 2 should be executed ahead of operation 1', but that's not what you've actually got going on in your code. Setting the priority of an operation higher than another doesn't guarantee it will be executed before. Normally that's what happens, but it's not *guaranteed*. If the order of the operations is important to you then you need to use dependencies (or a non-concurrent queue).

Comment: If you had suspended the queue before adding the operations and resumed it afterward, the priority will control which one is started first. The problem with the original code is that the queue could start operation 1 as soon as it's added before the higher-priority operation 2 has been added.